# Proving $ \ f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ $ f(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{x-1} , x<1 \\ \sqrt{x-1} , x \ge 1 \end{cases}$ is a bijection

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, piecewise-continuity

Question:

$ \ f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$

$ f(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{x-1} ,  x<1 \\
      \sqrt{x-1}  ,  x \ge 1 \end{cases}$

Prove that $ \ f$ is a bijection and find its inverse.

My attempt:

**Injective:**

Notice that $\ f(x) < 0, \forall x < 1$ and $\ f(x) \ge 0, \forall x \ge 1$.       (###)

Suppose $ f(a) = f(b) \implies a,b < 1$ or $\  a,b \ge 1$ by (###)

If $\ a,b < 1 \implies \frac{1}{a-1} = \frac{1}{b-1} \implies b-1 = a-1 \implies a = b$

If $ \ a,b \ge 1 \implies \sqrt{a-1} = \sqrt{b-1} \implies a - 1 = b -1 \implies a = b$

**Surjective:**

Pick any $ \ y \in \mathbb{R}$.

If $ \ y\ge 0  \implies y^2 \ge 0 \implies y^2 +1 \ge 1$. So, $ \ f(y^2 +1) = \sqrt{y^2} = |y| = y$, since $\  y \ge 0$.

If $ \ y< 0 \implies \frac{1}{y} < 0 \implies \frac{1}{y} + 1 < 1.$  So, $ \ f(\frac{1}{y} + 1) = y$

Inverse:

I tried to find the inverse using the proof for surjective .

$ f(x) = \begin{cases} x^2 + 1 ,  x \ge 0 \\
      \frac{1}{x} + 1  ,  x < 0 \end{cases}$

Is this the correct approach to prove a piecewise function is a bijection?

Comment: I think it's OK.

Comment: By (###) can't I omit that case?

Comment: Good point in your proof is (###) I think!

Comment: Looks fine to me too.

Comment: Why $f(a)=f(b)$ imply $a,b<1$ or...

Comment: I still don't understand.